# Rear wheel rubbing frame

Tags: rear-wheel

[image]

I notice when I tighten my quick release it centres but when I tighten the boot side it starts to get out of centre.
Could it be my quick release??
I have a 2017 giant atx 2

Comment: Does your axle wobble?

Comment: By 'boot side' do you mean the adjustment nut on the derailleur side? Are you  tightening that until the quick release starts to get tight?

Comment: Is the axis of the wheel centred? When did it start to rub? Are the spokes tightened equally around the wheel?

Comment: See here, how to tighten it correctly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hcq-PwYj3TE

Comment: Please provide picture of QR from both sides.

Comment: Why is this a Community Wiki ?